# How to clear alarmManager set() when startService is called again

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I have a service with following design:

```
MyService extends Service {
    onStartCommand() {
        ...
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService)
        alarmManager.set(...); 
    }
}
```

Hoe can I clear the alarmManager when startService is called multiple times so the alarmManager triggers a receiver only once?

Comment: Check whether service is running or not before start a service. Start a service frequently is bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the same pending intent and cancel (see [AlarmManager's cancel() docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent))) the old alarm with alarmmanager.cancel(pendingIntent).

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel(android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: How is the pending intent 'the same'? could you please provide a simple code sample?

Comment: Silly mistake, I finally realized it means making the same requestCode of the pendingIntent